# make a function return false if an element already exits

Tags: jquery

I have to find an element in the DOM and if the element exits jquery function should return false.How can i do this?
I did like this but doesnot work.
if($('.myclass').find('#id')== true) return false;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, jQuery functions that take a selector return a jQuery object that is like an array - you can check its `.length` property to see how many elements matched.

```
if ($('.myclass').find('#id').length > 0) return false
```

Comment: Yes, that's what my code does. If the id already exists then `$('.myclass').find('#id')` will return a jQuery object with a `.length` of 1 (I'm assuming there's only one element with that id) and of course `1 > 0` so it will return false.

Comment: @simplybj - if the jQuery object has any elements in it (e.g. it's length > 0), then the object from the jQuery exists.

Comment: Note that `$("#id").length` is enough to select your element (if it exists) - no need to select by `$('.myclass')` unless you want to explicitly check that "#id" is a child of ".myclass" (and not a child of something else).

Answer (score 1):

You can check the `length` property of a jQuery collection.

```
if ($('.myclass #id').length) {
   return false;
}
```

Comment: Cleaner! `val()` and `text()` are both falsy; don't have to compare to `0` or `""`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `length` property:

```
if($('.myclass  #id').length > 0) { return false };
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just want to see if an element with a given ID already exists or not.  If so then you can just do the following

```
var alreadyExists = $('#theId').length() > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($(...).size()) {
    return false;    
}
```

Comment: size uses `.length` property internally so directly using the `.length` will save you the overhead of a function call...

Answer (score 0):

Taking this a little further, you could always fashion a jQuery method for it.

```
$.fn.exists = function () {
    return this.length > 0;
};

// use it like this
var foo = $('#bar');
if (foo.exists()) {
    // do backflips
}
```

Maybe a little overboard, I know. Your mileage will vary. But I personally think it's more readable than `.length > 0` every single time I countercheck existence.

#### EDIT

As alex points out above, you could also use just plain `.length` to check for *truthy-ness*, and that'll work perfectly as well. Saves you a function call overhead, if you're looking for brevity.